# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart when converting .docx document to .pdf

Tags: java, spring

I have a java program named `wordToPdf` that converts the `*.docx` file to the `*.pdf` file. The program runs pretty well with `Apache POI 4.1.2` along with `POI OOXML 4.1.2` and the `fr.opensagres.xdocreport 2.0.2`. The `*.pdf` result is created successfully.

Below is the java program

```
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import java.io.*;

public void wordToPdf(String inDocFile, String outPdfFile) {
    try {
        File src = new File(inDocFile);
        InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(src);
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
        PdfOptions options = null;
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outPdfFile));
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, when the program is called from an `HttpServletRequest`, it doesn't work the same as the above scenario. In stead, the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception of `org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart` is returned.

Has anyone experienced this issue previously?

Please help me. Thanks so much, guys.

Comment: check the if the POI libs added to the WAR file?

Comment: @PrasadU thanks for response. i found it's there.